# React-Native bottom tab with two slides and horizontal scrolling

Tags: react-native

Any One can help me to create the react native bottom tabs with two slides and horizontal scrolling using "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs" library,

each slide will contains 5 tabs in it , when I scroll horizontally like left/right another slide should comes with new bottom tabs ,

I created bottom tabs by using "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs" library with 10 tabs but all of them are displaying in a single slide which makes the bottom tab UI not good looking ,

I am stucked in this issue from several days , please help me overcome from this issue,

Actual result : I created bottom tabs by using "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs" library with 10 tabs but all of them are displaying in a single slide which makes the bottom tab UI not good looking ,

Expected result : display each 5 tabs on two separate slides , when scrolling horizontally next slide should be display with another 5 bottom tabs,

like UI displaying in attached images